# How to check if the mouse clicked on a specific area in XNA Framework

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

Hy guys! I am in trouble checking if the mouse has clicked on a specific "button".

I check (MouseState.Leftbutton) first to be "Pressed" then i check the area i want to.

it works well when i click on the "button", but if i click somewhere near the button, and i drag the mouse on the button keeping the button pressed, it acts if i would pressed the button because (mouseState.Leftbutton = Pressed) and the mouse is in the area, both occurs at once.

How can i check mouse coordinates  at the moment of pressing down the left mouse button?

Sorry for bad english :D

Answer (score 0):

I strongy advise you against "Pressed"(or Click) event. Use MouseDown and MouseUp events instead. If you try to use any button in "official" applications - you can see it is mostly MouseUp event (or less common MouseDown)

Comment: Since i don't work with windows forms, that is not an option. Any solution in Xna?

Comment: Well, you could porbably always create it. But why not save the area where the pressed first occured and compare it with the area where it was released?

Answer (score 0):

```
Mouse.GetState().X 
Mouse.GetState().Y
```

These are the co-ordinates of your mouse position. If you are trying to do a click on a button ,follow this method.

let your button coordinates be buttonPostion.X and buttonPosition.Y on the screen.

then,

```
MouseState mouseClick = Mouse.GetState();
if (Mouse.GetState().X == buttonPosition.X && Mouse.GetState().Y == buttonPosition.Y)
    {
    if (mouseClick.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        //Your process when the button is pressed
    }
}
```

I hope I answered your question more or less.